# Get ID number from open/active Outlook email/window, find it in Excel and take user to row containing value

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am including a URL to my spreadsheet in an email like so:

Email:

```
This is some text
ID: 4

Url: C:\mySpreadhseet.xls
```

My spreadsheet:

```
Row 1    Column A         Column B
Row 2     ID               
Row 3     1
Row 4     2
Row 5     3
Row 6     4
```

The user can click the URL in the email which will open my spreadsheet and, on a workbook open event using VBA, I want to add a code which will scan the opened email / active window in outlook for the ID number in the email body, and then in my spreadsheet I want it to scroll to and highlight the row which contains that ID number.

So in this instance the user will be taken to row 6 in my spreadsheet and this entire row will be highlighted.

So far I have been doing some research on how to reference the opened email or active window in Outlook using VBA but I am not sure how I could utilize this to do what I need it to.

Please can someone point me in the right direction and show me how I might do this?

Researched source to reference active Outlook window:

```
Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()


Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The `objItem` object represents the selected item in Outlook. If it is not null, then you may look for the ID in the message body. The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to find the ID.

Then you can automate Excel for opening the mentioned in the mail item file and navigating the line specified in the email. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219151) for more information.

Finally, you may find the following articles helpful:

- [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)